# The spectrum of a quadratic matrix polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a monic quadratic matrix polynomial:

$$M(\lambda) = \lambda^2 I + \lambda A + B$$

Where $A$ is a real diagonal matrix, $B$ is a real positive semidefinite matrix (symmetric).

We are looking for the solution of the quadratic eigenvalue problem that it is the set of eigenvalues $\lambda$ and nontrivial eigenvectors $\psi$ such that $M(\lambda)\psi=0$.

In a particular case of $A = a I$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$, the spectrum of $M (\lambda) $ could be described in terms of the spectrum of $B$ in the following way. Eigenvectors are the same and eigenvalues of $M(\lambda) $ are the solution of $$ \lambda^2 + a\lambda + d = 0$$ 
Where $d$ - eigenvalue of $B$.

Is there any connection between the spectrum of $M(\lambda)$ and the spectrum of $B$ with any diagonal $A$?

---

### Update

Because $B$ is symmetric it is diagonalizable by orthogonal eigenvectors $B = Q D Q^T$. Then the original polynomial could be represented as the following 
$$Q^T M(\lambda) Q = \lambda^2I + \lambda Q^T AQ + D$$

It is clear that in the mentioned particular case of $A = aI$, the term $Q^T A Q = a I$ and the matrix $Q^T M(\lambda) Q$ becomes diagonal and $\text{det}[Q^T M(\lambda) Q] = \prod_j \lambda^2 + a\lambda + d_j$.

Is it possible to exploit the fact that $A$ is diagonal to simplify $\text{det}[Q^T M(\lambda) Q]$?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to write them explicitly in terms of entries of matrices, but it should be possible to write their characteristic polynomial in terms of entries of matrices.

Comment: It seems that you are not looking for the eigenvalues of $M(\lambda)$, but you are looking for roots of the polynomial equation $\det M(\lambda)=0$. They are different things.

Comment: @i707107 probably there is an abuse of terminology. I am looking for the solution of the quadratic polynomial problem $M(\lambda)\psi=0$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_eigenvalue_problem). In this case eigenvalues and roots of a polynomial equation $\det M(\lambda)=0$ are the same.

Comment: When you use $\phi_i^T A \phi_j=0$, are you assuming that $B$ can be diagonalized by orthogonal eigenvectors?

Comment: @i707107 yes, I am because $B$ is semidefinite and, consequently, symmetric.

Comment: It is the other way around. The spectral theorem states that if $B$ is real symmetric, then $B$ can be diagonalized by orthogonal eigenvectors. So, your assumption for the problem should be "$B$ is symmetric, and $B$ is positive semidefinite.$

Comment: @i707107 You are right, I've modified the text